# Guice Type Literal Bindings

Tags: java, generics, binding, guice

Is it possible to bind dinamically a generic type in Guice ?

I know is it possible to do for example :

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<SomeInterface<String>>(){})
    .to(SomeImplementation.class);
```

But, is possible to create a TypeLiteral  dinamically ??? . I want to mean ,  in the example i know to bidn SomeInterface to SomeImplementation ..... but what about if i want to do this dinamically ...

For example if i have String1, String2,....String "n" ...  is possible to do a function similar like this pseudocode

```
   function (Class<?> interfaceWithoutType, Clas<?>  type , Class<?> implementingClass) {
        TypeLiteral typeLiteral = **"createTypeLiteral"** (interfaceWithoutType, type);
        bind ( typeLiteral).to(implementingClass)
    }
```

Is it possible to make something similar, maybe with Refections?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work although I haven't test-compiled it:

```
private <T> void bindSomeInterface(Class<T> typeParameter, Class<? extends SomeInterface<T>> implementation) {
    Type parameterizedType = Types.newParameterizedType(SomeInterface.class, typeParameter);
    bind((TypeLiteral<SomeInterface<T>>) TypeLiteral.get(parameterizedType))
            .to(implementation);
}
```

But I'd recommend just doing it by hand instead.